# Set a divs height to match the divs width when using a percentage and media query's for the width

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, media-queries

I have a grid of divs that need to change the height to match the width of the div. I have used to media querys and jquery to achieve this however after the jquery runs not all the divs are the same height. Is there something I have missed in the jquery?

JQuery

```
var setFeedItem = function () {
  console.log($(this).css('width'));
  $(this).css('height', $(this).width());
};

$('#feed .feed_item').each(setFeedItem);
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('#feed .feed_item').each(setFeedItem);
});
```

CSS:

```
.feed_item {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
.feed_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 2500px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 10%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 12.5%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .feed_item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="feed">
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand1.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand3.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand2.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand1.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand2.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand1.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="feed_item"><img src="images/rand3.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

It could be the media queries interfering with the jQuery, but any help would be great as this keeps breaking my layout.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm understanding correct, you want square responsive blocks? In that case, you don't need jQuery. You can use a padding-bottom on your elements, to give them a "responsive" height.

```
.feed_item{
  width:20%;
  background:red;
  padding-bottom:20%;
}
```

If you want an image in those blocks, that scales to the size of `.feed_item`, you can add `position:relative` to `.feed_item` and position the `img` absolute. Check out this pen:

http://codepen.io/SamP/pen/GqrypX